# Read VBA constant from VSTO add-in?

Tags: vba, vsto

Is it possible for an Excel VSTO add-in to read a constant from the vba code of a workbook?  For example I have two constants stored in a module of all excel workbooks I have created

```
Public Const APPName As String = "test_app"
Public Const APPVersion As Double = 1.02
```

What I would like to do is pull these constants from the Application_WorkbookOpen sub of my VSTO add-in.  I need this information to determine if the user should be able to open and modify the file, and log usage.

Comment: I haven't done this kind of thing from VSTO, but I imagine you can.  Here's a great guide for doing it from VBA: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is quite old but for reference ... i just got the same requirement and solved it using a function which can be called from VSTO (in this example `GetAppName`) that returns the desired value.

`string appName = (string)Application.Run(string.Format("'{0}'!GetAppName", Application.ActiveWorkbook.Name));`